# What happens when changing ORMLite database structure within an app

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite database in my android application, now I want to change the whole structure of the Database like (renaming tables, add/remove columns, change relations, ...etc).

The question here, is there are any conflicts would happen in the devices with my app previously installed? in another words, when updating the app, is ORMLite leave any trails from the previous install that would make conflicts with the new one?!! so if I have a table named `parent` and I changed its name to `guardian` will I have two tables now in the new release?!!

If the answer is **No**, so why there is something like database version?

and if the answer is **Yes**, so how would I drop a table that is not exist anymore in my application? and can I just use the same class name with a different table name annotation to override the previous table?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used ORMLite specifically. But it's just an ORM which means, it will won't decide if the table would be dropped or not based on a certain condition. That is something client has to do specifically based on their business rules. Now in Android there are specific ways you can upgrade the current database schema without dropping existing tables - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

But upgrading database schema on SQLIte has lots of limitations i.e. there are so many operations that are not supported unlike a full blown DBMS.But that's part of the reason why SQLite is so light. Generally during your development cycle, try to conclude to a stable database schema as early as possible which needs minor additions later (SQLIte specifically does not support removing columns and etc.). Once you are in production and you don't wanna play with user's data, implementing an upgrade logic is the best bet you got.

But if you still want to drop a table explicitly, i see there are API's for the same in ORMLite -

http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtils.html

Comment: unfortunately this won't help me in my situation, you gave me assumptions not facts, and the TableUtils API is used indeed in dropping tables but an existing ones.